# Is chaos-based encryption legitimate?

Tags: encryption

Is chaos-based encryption a rigorous discipline? And why there are objections to it within the cryptography community? And why are many of its cryptosystems weak? And does it has a promising future? And is there any example of secure cryptographic systems based on chaos?

Also, some people differentiate between the legitimacy of analog vs digital chaos-based cryptography, is this right?

The most important question: given the criticism, why do scientific journals still publish these systems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These papers typically appear in generalist journals and conferences and not in focused cryptographic venues.

There is no serious reason which has been demonstrated to consider continuous systems including those with chaotic behaviour as useful building blocks for cryptography.

There are many reasons; one of the most important is that chaos is hard to control and does not give predictability required to establish provable security parameters required for state of the art cryptographic strength of current day
cryptosystems.

There is more under this question:[Explaining Chaotic Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64723/explaining-chaotic-cryptography)

Another question with extensive discussion including well known experts is here:

[What's the truth about this "absolutely unbreakable" cipher?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76570/whats-the-truth-about-this-absolutely-unbreakable-cipher)

Comment: But it seems like a pandemic. How can we ignore this huge amount of paper? Even more, how could the public trust the scientific papers anymore?

Comment: @Theprince The amount of bad crypto papers is so huge that filtering them out is doomed. The problem is best dealt with by selecting what papers to read. One strategy is to select among papers recommended by pepole one has good reasons to trust, [publications of the IACR](https://www.iacr.org/publications/), and other selected conferences including (in no way limited to) [CCS](https://dl.acm.org/conference/ccs), [ACNS](http://jianying.space/acns/).

Comment: @Maeher: fixed, thanks (I'll delete this sometime).